# SXHKD won't stop running script

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, hotkeys, window-manager

So I'm having some difficulty with SXHKD - I run this with BSPWM for context. I recently wrote a script that's able to find all windows in the active monitor, then select the desired desktop from that monitor. The script works great and all, but when I try to use this script in SXHKD, everything falls apart. Using the hotkeys: alt + {1-9,0} works, but continues to run the script even after I'm finished pressing alt. I'll have the script below:

- SXHKDRC bit

  ```
   alt + {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} 

   input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; \ 

   echo "$input" | ~/.config/bspwm/.scripts/get_active_monitors_desktops.sh
  ```
- Get desktop from active monitor:

  ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   desktops=()
   counter=1

   for i in $(bspc query -D -m); do
     desktops[$counter]="$i"
     counter=$(("$counter+1"))
   done

   select=$(cat)

   if [ "$select" -gt ${#desktops[@]} ] || [ "$select" -lt 1 ]; then
     return
   fi

   $(bspc desktop -f "${desktops[$select]}")
  ```

I've got a temporary fix for this right now, and, that is, I use **pkill -USR1 -x -sxhkd**, but I'm not really happy about it. I want to be able to spam through all my windows as quick as my fingers can move - I can't right now, because last time I tried, my computer crashed. Your time and help is appreciated!

[**edit #1**] So I implemented some of @Counthchrisdo's code because of his superior bash knowledge, but I'm still experiencing the same issue - that is, unless I use a chord chain alt + o for me. Also, make sure to use ; \ after every separate line in your sxhkdrc, otherwise it won't work. I've replaced:

```
alt + {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; \        
echo "$input" | ~/.config/bspwm/.scripts/get_active_monitors_desktops.sh
```

with:

`alt + {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; \ 
echo "$input" | ~/.config/bspwm/.scripts/get_active_monitors_desktops.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

I'm assuming he closed the pipe I opened up with ***cat*** so I thought this was going to work for sure. Any other leads?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your script is not exiting properly, causing it to continue executing even after the keybinding has been released. Here's an updated version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

desktops=()
counter=1

for i in $(bspc query -D -m); do
    desktops[$counter]="$i"
    counter=$((counter+1))
done

select=$(cat)

if [ "$select" -gt ${#desktops[@]} ] || [ "$select" -lt 1 ]; then
    exit 1  # Exit with an error code if the selection is out of range
fi

$(bspc desktop -f "${desktops[$select]}")

exit 0  # Exit successfully after the action is performed
```

Changes made:

```
Added exit 1 to indicate an error if the selection is out of range.
Added exit 0 to indicate successful execution after changing the desktop.
```

Make sure the script has executable permissions (chmod +x script_name.sh) and update your SXHKD config to handle the script properly:

```
alt + {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
echo "$input" | ~/.config/bspwm/.scripts/get_active_monitors_desktops.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This version of the script should exit properly after changing the desktop, preventing it from continuing to execute after releasing the keybinding in SXHKD. Make sure to redirect the script output to /dev/null to suppress any output.

Comment: Hey @Counthchrisdo! I tried doing what you said with the script and the sxhkdrc, but I still end up with the problem. I fixed my problem earlier by adding a chord to the command: alt + f ; {1,2,...,9,0}. Thank you for showing me some neat bash tricks though!

Comment: Darn I was sure my fix would work, I'm glad you figured it out though!